# Bootstrap tagsinput + typeahead

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Есть текстовая форма, где введённые пользователем значения превращаются в теги (tagsinput). При вводе снизу появляется подсказка (typeahead).

Позже я получаю из этого поля массив значений и сохраняю в базу. Всё работает отлично и как нужно, однако при клике в подсказку, появляющуюся снизу или при нажатии enter (в обоих случаях введённое значение превращается в тег) в консоль валится ошибка:

> bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'apply' of undefined

Связка typeahead + tagsinput для данного поля настроена так:

```
$($myField).tagsinput({
            itemValue: 'id',
            itemText: 'name',
            typeahead: {
              displayKey: 'name',
              source: data['security_list']
            }
          });
```

где 'id', 'name' - названия соответствующих атрибутов из справочника, который загружен в виде JSON.

Среда: backbone, все разбито по модулям, которые грузятся через require. (если данные о среде тут вообще нужны)

Где выпрямлять руки?